# Combine for and while loop (Java)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to make a program that allows the user to input 100 numbers and if the user writes '0', then the program is suppose to print the smallest, largest, sum and all the numbers. I got all that to work but not to exit and print it all. My teacher said something about using a while loop, but how is that possible when you have a for loop?

Regards

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] list = new int[100];
    int min = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    boolean first = true;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(list[i] != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

            System.out.print("Enter number (0 to exit) " + (1 + i) + ":");
            list[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

            if (first == true) {

            min = list[i];
            first = false;
        }

        if (list[i] < min) {

            min = list[i];
        }

        else if (list[i] > max) {

            max = list[i];
        }

        sum = list[i] + sum;

    }

    if (list[i] == 0) {

    System.out.print("Numbers are: " + list[0] + ", ");

    for (int i = 1; i < list.length; i++)

    System.out.print(list[i] + ", ");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Smallest number is: " + min);
    System.out.println("Largest numeber is: " + min);
    System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
    }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Well then maybe the `for` loop is not appropriate ? Either you use a `for` loop and have an `if` inside or you have a `while` loop and have a variable to act as a counter.

Comment: A "for loop" is a specialization of a "while" loop (or, for that matter, a "do/while" loop).  You can do everything in a while loop that you can in a for loop.  You  can also nest loops, one inside another.

Comment: For descends from while, which descends from boolean recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the body of the method which will do what you've been asked. I have not used a while loop (but in fact, a for-loop is a kind of a while-loop internally).

```
int size = 100; // Set the number of numbers to input.
int[] list = new int[size]; // Create an array with 'size' elements.
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // Set the highest possible integer as start value.
int max = 0; // Set the minimum to zero, assuming that the user won't input negative numbers.
int sum = 0; // Initialize the sum of the numbers in the list.

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // Run 'size' times the process of inputting a number.
    System.out.print("Enter number (0 to exit) " + (i + 1) + ": ");
    int number = scan.nextInt();
    if (number == 0) { // Quit program if input equals '0'
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
        break;
    }
    list[i] = number; // Add the current number to the list
    sum += number; // Add the number to the total
    if (number < min) { // If the number is smaller than the previous one, set this number as the smallest
        min = number;
    }
    if (number > max) { // If the number is greater than the previous smallest number, set this number as the greatest
        max = number;
    }
}

// Output all numbers in the list
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] != 0) {
        System.out.print((i == 0 ? "" : ", ") + list[i]);
    }
}

// You see the snippet (i == 0 ? "" : ", ")
// That is a shorthand if-else statement:
// If i equals 0, then "" (empty string), else ", " (comma and space).
// The statement
//     System.out.print((i == 0 ? "" : ", ") + list[i])
// is the same as
//     if (i == 0) {
//         System.out.println("") + list[i];
//     }
//     else {
//         System.out.println(", ") + list[i];
//     }

System.out.println("Smallest number is: " + min);
System.out.println("Largest numeber is: " + max);
System.out.println("Sum is: " + sum);
```

Comment: Oh thank you. I'm sorry I formulated the task so badly but its not just suppose to exit, it has to print the numbers, smallest biggest etc aswell

Comment: Updated. Just use `break` instead of `System.exit(0)`. Break will exit the current loop and continue execution of the code.

Comment: Ops, didnt read it through properly. Thank you very much! You dont happen to now how to get rid of the zeros when you exit?

Comment: @user1905426: Please vote up and mark the question as answered if it is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You only need one while loop to do this and additionally a for loop just to print the array if you want:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;
int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int[] history = new int[100];
System.out.println("INPUT:");
int option = scan.nextInt();
while (option != 0 && i <= 100)
{
    if (option > maxValue)
        maxValue=option;
    sum += option;
    history[i] = option;
    option = scan.nextInt();
    i++;
}
System.out.println("OUTPUT: \n" + "SUM: " + sum + "\n MAX VALUE: " + maxValue);
for (int x : history)
    System.out.print(x + "");
```

Comment: Thank you! But how do i get rid of the zeros? The task is make it print "The numbers are: 1, 3, 7"

Comment: @user1905426 if you want to get rid of all the zeros i.e. incrementally add to the array, you need to use a dynamic structure like an arrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You have muddled code. Better to use a pattern like this:

```
while (true) {
    // read next
    if (input == 0) 
        break;
}
```

Comment: He also needs to keep track of the number of entries so far, and stop at 100.

Comment: But how im suppose to print out all the numbers with a while loop?